# C# MongoDB Adding an array to an array with Pusheach in combination with positional identifier always on position 0

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to add an array to a nested array in a document. For the right position in the array, i'm using the positional identifier for the update. Everything looks fine: the correct document is found, but the array is always added to position '0' and not (in my example below to position '1'). I'm strugling already a few days with it, but can't find the mistake i made. Maybe someone can give me clue.

this is the document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b3fad5fd38e401ae836497b"),
    "Supplier" : "5b367975d38e400a10d490ba",
    "MenuCard" : [ 
        {
            "CardDescription" : "Menu",
            "Category" : "Drinks",
            "Subcategory" : [ 
                {
                    "Title" : "Beer",
                    "Shortname" : "B",
                    "SubcategoryItems" : []
                }, 
                {
                    "Title" : "Wine",
                    "Shortname" : "W",
                    "SubcategoryItems" : []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

i'm trying to insert a new array into the array 'SubcategoryItems' with the title Wine:

```
public async Task<MongoResult> AddSubCategoryItemAsync(SubcategoryItem oAddNewSubCategoryItem)
{
    BsonDocument jsonSearch = new BsonDocument
    {
        { "Supplier", Customer},
        { "MenuCard.Category", Category },
        { "MenuCard.Subcategory.Title","Wine"}
    };

    SubcategoryItem oCategory = new SubcategoryItem { ItemId=oAddNewSubCategoryItem.ItemId,
                                                      ItemImageUrl=oAddNewSubCategoryItem.ItemImageUrl,
                                                      ItemName=oAddNewSubCategoryItem.ItemName,
                                                      ItemDescription=oAddNewSubCategoryItem.ItemDescription,
                                                      Price=oAddNewSubCategoryItem.Price};

    BsonArray doc = new BsonArray { new BsonDocument(oCategory.ToBsonDocument()) };

    try
    {
        var insert = Builders<BsonDocument>.Update.PushEach("MenuCard.0.Subcategory.$.SubcategoryItems", values: doc);
        var result = await _collection.UpdateOneAsync(jsonSearch, insert);

        return new MongoResult { Validate = true, Explanation = "SubCatItem added" };
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return new MongoResult { Validate = false, Explanation = e.ToString() };
    }
}
```

But when i run the code, it always add the array to the 'Beer' session.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b3fad5fd38e401ae836497b"),
    "Supplier" : "5b367975d38e400a10d490ba",
    "MenuCard" : [ 
        {
            "CardDescription" : "Menu",
            "Category" : "Drinks",
            "Subcategory" : [ 
                {
                    "Title" : "Beer",
                    "Shortname" : "B",
                    "SubcategoryItems" : [ 
                        {
                            "ItemId" : "AddA333",
                            "ItemImageUrl" : "WWW...",
                            "ItemName" : "White wine",
                            "ItemDescription" : "Dry",
                            "Price" : 1.46
                        }
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "Title" : "Wine",
                    "Shortname" : "W",
                    "SubcategoryItems" : []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I was expecting that the search gives for the $  the value 1, but it is always gives a 0. where do i make a mistake?

Answer (score 0):

edit: i don't think it is possible to use the PushEach in this scenario. I fixed it like this:

```
    var resultBsons = await _collection.Find<BsonDocument>(jsonSearch)
        .Project(Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection
                                            .Exclude("_id"))
                                            .ToListAsync();

    JObject json = JObject.Parse(resultBsons[0].ToJson());
    JArray MenuCard = (JArray)json["MenuCard"];
    var SubCat = MenuCard.Values("Subcategory").ToArray();

    int nReturn = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i <= SubCat.Count(); i++)
    {
        if ((string)SubCat[0][i]["Title"] == "Wine")
        {
            nReturn = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    string insertString = "MenuCard.0.Subcategory."+nReturn.ToString()+".SubcategoryItems";
```